# Need help pulling certain data out of a list

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a call Center Application that displays calls in queue in a bunch of other data to our analysts and managers. I'm trying to display the next three people in the queue to receive a call. I was able to put together the code below and reference max3 as an itemsource in a listbox but it doesn't actually display the names of the people next. when you add a breakpoint on max3 it shows the three agents that are next but it also shows all of their data, time in queue, extension number, stuff like that. i need to know how to only display their name.

```
List<NewAgent> newAgentList = new List<NewAgent>();
List<Tuple<String, TimeSpan>> availInItems = new List<Tuple<string, TimeSpan>>();

foreach (var item in e.CmsData.Agents)
{
    NewAgent newAgents = new NewAgent();

    newAgents.AgentName = item.AgName;

    newAgents.AgentExtension = item.Extension;

    newAgents.AgentDateTimeChange = ConvertedDateTimeUpdated;

    newAgents.AuxReasons = item.AuxReasonDescription;

    newAgents.LoginIdentifier = item.LoginId;

    newAgents.AgentState = item.WorkModeDirectionDescription;

    var timeSpanSince = DateTime.Now - item.DateTimeUpdated;
    newAgents.AgentDateTimeStateChange = timeSpanSince;

    newAgentList.Add(newAgents);

    if (item.WorkModeDirectionDescription == "AVAIL-IN")
    {
        availInItems.Add(Tuple.Create(newAgents.AgentName, timeSpanSince));
    }

    availInItems.Sort((t1, t2) => t1.Item2.CompareTo(t2.Item2));
}
```

Occurs after above code:

```
var availInAgents = newAgentList
        .Where(ag => ag.AgentState == "AVAILIN") .ToList();

availInAgents.Sort((t1, t2) =>
    t1.AgentDateTimeStateChange.CompareTo(t2.AgentDateTimeStateChange));

var minTimeSpanAgent = availInAgents.FirstOrDefault();
var maxTimeSpanAgent = availInAgents.LastOrDefault();

var min3 = availInAgents.Take(3).ToList();
var max3 = availInAgents.Skip(availInAgents.Count - 3);

max3.Reverse();
```

This is where my problem exists, it displays the info in the screen shot below. I only need the AgentName out of it and i don't know how to only access that piece of information. Please assist with this.

```
nextInLine.itemsource = max3.ToString();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [.Select()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) method to project a new type from your query.

```
nextInLine.itemsource = max3?.Select(x => x?.AgentName).FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```

It will take the first agent in `max3` and retrieve only the string `AgentName`, assigning it to `itemsource`.

The `?` in this case is the null propagation operator.  If `max3` is null, it will return null before evaluating the `.Select()` which, in conjunction with the Null Coalescing operator (??), will set the `itemsource` to an empty string.  It repeats this process if any item in your max3 list is null, or if AgentName itself is null.

Comment: so this worked. any chance you can help in compensating for a null value. when i use the select option sometimes it throws and error and says object reference not set to an instance of an object. this is why i didn't do this to begin with.

Comment: so that did fix the null reference error and now that it is not getting an error i've noticed it is displaying the agents names one letter per cell vertically. don't suppose you have an easy fix for that. when i use a text box instead of a listbox it displays the names correctly but is only displaying one name.

Comment: @firehotguitar88 at this point I don't think your current state reflects your current question.  You should either close this question and create a new, specific question that accurately represents your current state, or you need to modify this question to accurately represent the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: thank you. i've marked your answer correct as you were the first to respond

Comment: @firehotguitar88 happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Select` from Linq

```
var agentNamesFromMax3 = max3.Select(m => m.AgentName);
```